# Cannot install add-in for outlook 2007?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, outlook-addin

I'll explain here what I have done and I will be really grateful if someone helps me. I've seen there are some posts about this problem, but I want to know if I made some mistakes.

I developed add-in for Outlook 2007 (.NET Framework 3.5) using VS2008 and C#. When I finished, in Solution Explorer, right-click on "Solution(my project)" and clicked on Add New Project->Other Project Types->Setup and Deployment->Setup Project.

In this new project I have tab File System with 3 folders:

- Application folder
- User's desktop
- User's program menu

I clicked right click on Application folder->Add->Project Output---> Primary output (My Project)

After all this, in the Debug folder of added setup project there are setup.exe and MyProject.msi files, but when I install it on other computer, there's no add-in installed in Microsoft Outlook :(

What I did wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, deploying an Outlook add-in involves more than just creating a default setup project in Visual Studio. In particular, you need to add some registry entries to your setup project, which are required by Outlook to recognize your add-in; and you need to make sure that the prerequisites are installed. These two MSDN articles should get you started:

- [Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx)
- [Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc616991.aspx)

Since you are targeting Outlook 2007 (rather than 2003), using ClickOnce is a (supposedly easier) alternative to using a setup project:

- [Deploying Solutions for the 2007 Office System with ClickOnce Using Visual Studio 2008 Professional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb821233.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I succeed with ClickOnce but not so easy. Problem was W7. I couldn't find the way to install it on other computer. When I figured it out, I installed VS2008 on other comp with WinXP and published my project. It is working now. Thank you.